# WCF DataServices and dynamically changing datasets

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework, wcf-data-services

from what i've seen so far WCF Data Services are pretty easy to setup when using then in combination with EF.

That's kinda what i'm after out of the box but I also need the ability for the EF model to change at runtime.

I'm building an app where the app users will be able to specify the database structure and then begin populating it ... the relevant UI components needed are then generated with MVC using some clever rule based trickery.

So for example the user will be given a "Create new Object" button, which will let them specify field names.

Once that part is complete the user submits that and it generates a new table in the db. 
From there the UI components are generated that allow that table to be managed within the app.

The problem of course is getting that new table in to the EF model without a recompile of the back end data service.

The concept being that this builds the database and the pages required to manage the various parts of it (there's a bigger picture in mind here but i don't want to confuse matters by trying to explain it all).

I'm thinking that maybe EF is not the right tool to use at the moment .. because it needs a strongly typed set of entities in order to work ... that may not be possible in this case.

I'm toying with the idea of passing this service Dynamic objects ... (e.g. objects of type Something : dynamic )

Comment: `I'm thinking that maybe EF is not the right tool to use at the moment` So do I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG ...

Apparently this is supported (mostly) out the box with EF 4.2

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/09/28/ef-4-2-release-candidate-available.aspx

WOW !!!

Answer (score 1):

i'd suggest not only that entity framework is not right for this, but neither is a relational database.  document database or key-value store would probably be a better fit than trying to create tables on demand to shove this into a relational structure.

Comment: The data in question is most definately relational data ... to give this some context i'm sorta building a workflow engine that operates on objects of a yet unknown type ... when the user defines the process / flow they also define the objects on which they operate.

Answer (score 1):

WCF Data Services can be used without Entity Framework. Using either the "Reflection Provider" or a custom provider, which you will have to implement (the Reflection provider requires you to have actual .NET classes, which you don't).

Basically, you implement the DataService class and the IServiceProvider interface, which will provide instances of the IDataServiceQueryProvider, IDataServiceMetadataProvider and IDataServiceUpdateProvider. This might involve a lot of work, so be sure that you actually do want to do this.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee960143.aspx for more information.

Comment: This looks complicated ... i'll have a read through it and get back to you :)

Comment: It's definitly complicated, but it can be done. I've done it myself but for existing .NET classes, dynamic schemas will be a real big challenge. But judging from your amibitious project, you aren't afraid of this.

Comment: Does an EF DataContext implement all these interfaces ? ... heavy!!! ... doable though ... i'm interested to hear how your solution worked ?

Comment: An EF ObjectContext stores all the metadata for the entities which is than used by the DataService, if you don't use EF you have to provide the metadata and the references to IQueryable-sets yourself. I did this to have the DataService bound to a generic interface rather the EF context itself, which meant that I had entities and IQueryable-sets at hand, which you might not. If you plan to allow filters and such, you might need to provide a custom query-provider as well. I suggest you role your own RESTful AtomPub service, which mimics the behavior of OData (like $metadata and such).

Comment: this is kind of what i'm looking to achieve ... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa685870.aspx but i need to build the code that this talks to not this code obviously, do you think this is how microsoft did it ?

Comment: the only problem i have is that "Account" is not a defined type until the user specifies it by building it in the app.

Comment: Well, this sample isn't using an OData service. I guess you could always come up with an infrastructure that instead represents entities in form of dictionaries. Since the WCF Data Service wants to provide a rich API with type-safe entities, it might not fit your needs. I would say that the most interesting feature about it is it's query provider model. But this only works with actual entities, which is I why you should look out for other options.